# Distribute the returns of a loop among two sections

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I've basically got these two templates:

```
<article>
  <section>
    ...
  </section>
  <section>
    ...
  </section>
</article>
```

and:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  <h3> post.title </h3>
  <p> post.body </p>
  <hr />
```

I can replace `...` in `<section>` with `yield` and have every post in this section. Now what I want to do is to alternate this every turn so that each of the two sections gets filled up equally. I'm sure there must be some relatively easy way to achieve this? I somehow can't think of one for now.

**edit:** don't get me wrong. the first template can (and probably should) be merged with the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in the first section:

```
@posts.select.each_with_index{|_,i| i.even? }
```

and this in the other one:

```
@posts.select.each_with_index{|_,i| i.odd? }
```

If you don't mind that the elements are not alternating between the columns but go top to bottom, you can do:

```
<article>
  <% @posts.in_groups(2, false) do |grouped_posts| %>
  <section>
    <% grouped_posts.each do |post| %>
    <h3> post.title </h3>
    <p> post.body </p>
    <hr />
    <% end %>
  </section>
  <% end %>
</article>
```

Outside of Rails you can either pull in the necessary bits for `in_groups` from the active support gem

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/grouping'
```

or you can use this alternative approach which works very similarly:

```
@posts.each_slice((@posts.size/2.0).ceil).to_a
```

The only difference is:

```
@posts = []

@posts.in_groups(2, false)                         #=> [[], []]
@posts.each_slice((@posts.size/2.0).ceil).to_a     #=> []
```

Comment: Thanks! The last section seems to be exactly what I want. However I'm using Sinatra and `in_groups()` seems to be a Rails method? :(

Comment: you can either add `gem 'activesupport'` to your Gemfile and `require 'active_support/core_ext/array/grouping'`, or you can copy it from here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/grouping.rb

Comment: Added `false` as second argument to `in_groups`. Otherwise there will be a `nil` when you have an odd number of elements. Also added another option which does not require Rails